# Flutter : Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: firebase, dart, exception

I'm working on flutter/firebase project. And there is some issue in this code :

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Volunteers/"+vname);
        db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
          values.forEach((key,values) {
              print(values["cont"]);
          });
        });
```

Upon running, I get this error `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think the values in foreach is not an  object, it looks like an array, so the error in this { print(values["cont"]);}...
If its not that error, print both "values" and see what they are.

One more hint, sometimes in the console, when you get error, will also get the line where that error exists, especially in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Here.
`value` is the value for the key. what you thought was `values['const']` is actually just `value`.

```dart
values.forEach((key,value) {
  print(value);
});
```

**Note**: `values` was renamed to `value` fore conciseness